# Login Page issues Visual Studio C# for asp.net for a Digital Solutions Class Project

Tags: c#

My class and I cant figure out how to get our login page to work. We need it take us to different pages, one for admin and one for a normal person based on the login ID. So if the ID matches the ID for an admin it will take it to a page for the admin, but a normal ID when a normal person makes their account it will take them to our welcome page. We're coding in C# on Visual Studio. Ill update this if we figure it out for anyone else asking this question. This what we got so far.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="CleanIA3.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>`your text`
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
          
            <center>  <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="~/success.aspx"></asp:Login></center>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Success page is the page that it takes a normal user to when they login, we are yet to figure out the admin part.

We've tried DestinationPageURL and it didnt work.